# trouble in getting data using PeriodicalUpdater

Tags: ajax, prototypejs

I am confused about the problem below using JS:

```
var abc='';
var on=new Ajax.PeriodicalUpdater("onlinelist","URL",
    {
        method:'get',
        onSuccess:function(transport){
            abc+=transport.response;
        },
        frequency:1000
     }
);
if(abc!=='') {
    on.stop();
    alert(abc);
}
```

However, the alert is empty; If I replace the `alert(abc);` line with `alert('123');alert(abc);`

Then I'll get the expected contents from `transport.response`

I checked many materials and don't know why this happens.
I hope someone can point out the reason and fix it without adding the extra first alert.

Answer (score 0):

`frequence` should be `frequency`. I'm assuming the other values are just placeholders.

The `alert` will fire before the Ajax request has a chance to complete, and no alert is called as a result of the following Ajax requests.

See a (modified) [working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/davelnewton/9ANhh/).

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the mistake. I have modified it. And the point is I want to stop the Ajax.PeriodicalUpdater after several times. Then get abc. Like what the codes appears now:alert in "if" part, my running stopped, and if there is one "alert" , abc is empty. If there are two "alert" in the "if" part, abc is not empty. That's strange .

Comment: @JimLally But your check for a value in `abc` happens outside the updater--if you need to do something based on the results of the updater, it obviously needs to happen in the `success` function. Code outside the updater will only run once.

Comment: Ohh, is there some better ideas to stop the updater~?I got your meaning , however , even if I change frequency to 1, the updater only run once, which means outside code on.stop() works. And the alert problem happens.

Comment: See the [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/davelnewton/9ANhh/). And remember, [accept and/or upvote answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) so future visitors with similar problems can benefit from your work!